# How to utilize "if" condition in a link using JSON column formatting in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink, json-formatting, column-formatting, if-condition

I am trying to remove all of "AAA" links from a link column called "LinkList" using JSON column formatting.

"AAA" is a link not text. I am in trouble to hide all of this kind of cells in that column.

Tried some coding, but most of them hide all this column or just made some links unavailable.

Please help me.
Thanks!

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField.desc",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "=if("LinkList"==[$AAA], ‘hide’ , '’)",
    "Target": "_blank"
  }
}
```

Comment: How you have added "AAA" as a URL in hyperlink field? It should either be like `http://AAA` or `https://AAA`.

Answer (score 1):

As you are saying:

> "AAA" is a link not text

I believe it should either be like `http://AAA` or `https://AAA`.

So in that case you can use below JSON code to hide the links with `http://AAA` or `https://AAA`:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "a",
    "txtContent": "@currentField.desc",
    "attributes": {
        "href": "=if((@currentField=='http://AAA' || @currentField=='https://AAA'),'#',@currentField)",
        "target": "_blank"
    },
    "style":{
        "display":"=if((@currentField=='http://AAA' || @currentField=='https://AAA'),'none','block')"
    }
}
```

**Original List values (Before formatting)**:

[image]

**Output (After formatting)**:

[image]

**Official documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting).

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the column formatting below to achieve it.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField.desc",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "=if(@currentField.desc=='AAA','#',@currentField)",
    "Target": "_blank"
  },
  "style":{
    "display":"=if(@currentField.desc=='AAA','none','block')"
  }
}
```